# Changing position of Custom Info Window of GoogleMap Marker android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have added a custom InfoWindow to my GoogleMap object as below

```
      mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() 
      {
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) 
            {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) 
            {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_info_window_layout,null,false);
                TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                TextView desc  = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc);
                TextView level = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.level);
                final int position = Integer.valueOf(marker.getSnippet());

                Players player = playersArray.get(position);
                title.setText(player.name);
                level.setText("Level " + String.valueOf(player.level));
                return v;
            }
```

Works good. However I the arrow tip of my layout is quite far from marker. So i want to add an offset of, let us say 50px at least.

According to the documentation given here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

*`anchorPoint : The offset from the marker's position to the tip of an InfoWindow that has been opened with the marker as anchor.`*

However When i do this

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
         .position(p)
         .anchor(0,50)
         .snippet(String.valueOf(position))
         .draggable(false)
         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```

Markers just disappear and don't even show..
What is wrong? Without anchor option they work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at the moment. If anyone can find Please post here.

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong?

What is wrong is that you are reading the JavaScript API documentation. That's why there is `javascript` in the URL.

The Maps V2 for Android documentation for `MarkerOptions` tells [a different story for `anchor()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#anchor%28float,%20float%29):

> The anchor point is specified in the continuous space [0.0, 1.0] x [0.0, 1.0], where (0, 0) is the top-left corner of the image, and (1, 1) is the bottom-right corner.

Comment: I have an infoWindow image of size 220 * 75 and its anchor point is at 200*60 Now I want to put it in the middle of the marker but atm it is at the right extreme of 0.marker. According to above i have tried setting (0.9f,0.8f) but still markers don't show up

Comment: @MuhammadUmar: I have not personally used `anchor()`, as I have been happy with `getInfoContents()` instead of `getInfoWindow()`. My answer was merely to point out that a `(0,50)` value, as you used originally, definitely would not work.

Comment: in my case getInforContents show a White Rectangle over my custom infoWindow so I used getInfoWindow